# How can i update table without id

Tags: php, laravel

My client wants to make his logo dynamic in website. So, in dashboard i have included a field name "Settings" in admin dashboard where he can change his logo. For this i need to update my settings table without id because initially there won't be any data in the database. To update a table without creating need "id".Because of this i am facing a problem. 
Suggest me if there are other alternatives to make the logo dynamic in the web page.

```
<form action="{{route('updatesettings',['id'=>$settings->id])}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="changelogo">CHANGE LOGO</label><br>
        <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control ">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="changelogo">CHANGE Image for About Home page</label><br>
        <input type="file" name="image1" class="form-control ">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="changelogo">CHANGE First Image for About page</label><br>
        <input type="file" name="image2" class="form-control ">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="changelogo">CHANGE Second Image for About page</label><br>
        <input type="file" name="image3" class="form-control ">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="about">About</label>
        <textarea name="about" class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">update</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

controller

```
public function updatesettings(Request $request)
    {

        $data['about'] = $request->about;
        if($request->hasFile('image'))
        {
                $image = $request->file('image');
                $ext=$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $imageName = md5(microtime()).'.'.$ext;
                $uploadPath = public_path('uploaded/');
                if($image->move($uploadPath,$imageName))
                {
                    $data['image'] = $imageName;
                }
        }
        if($request->hasFile('image1'))
        {
                $image = $request->file('image1');
                $ext=$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $imageName = md5(microtime()).'.'.$ext;
                $uploadPath = public_path('uploaded/');
                if($image->move($uploadPath,$imageName))
                {
                    $data['image1'] = $imageName;
                }
        }
        if($request->hasFile('image2'))
        {
                $image = $request->file('image2');
                $ext=$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $imageName = md5(microtime()).'.'.$ext;
                $uploadPath = public_path('uploaded/');
                if($image->move($uploadPath,$imageName))
                {
                    $data['image2'] = $imageName;
                }
        }
        if($request->hasFile('image3'))
        {
                $image = $request->file('image3');
                $ext=$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $imageName = md5(microtime()).'.'.$ext;
                $uploadPath = public_path('uploaded/');
                if($image->move($uploadPath,$imageName))
                {
                    $data['image3'] = $imageName;
                }
        }
        if(Setting::first()->update($data))
        {
            return redirect()->route('showsettings');
        }
        return redirect()->route('showsettings');

    }
```

> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\odan\resources\views\admin\modules\settings\setting.blade.php)

Comment: ```<form action="{{route('updatesettings',['id'=>$settings->id])}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to keep a default data for it. Make a database table for logo . initially you can keep "defaultimg" and when the user wants to update it take that row id and update it and if you will have only 1 logo then make a validation that user cannt add more than 1 data in that table ("logo" table). Hope you get it .

Answer (score 0):

As you said Initially there will be no data right. Then why you passing id from `form`. And from your question its looking like there will be always one entry in the `settings` table.

So Make a simple `route` without id and show data by fetching from setting `Setting::first() // instially empty`

then on hit submit update you model by doing

```
$setting = Setting::first();
$setting->myfields = $fileds;
$setting->save();
```

thats it.

Even you can use [updateOrCreate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models) method of laravel